# Uneven spacing in man pages

Tags: 20.04, manpage

What I have observed is that there is uneven spacing in the text in the man pages. Between some words there is a single space, where as some words have a double spacing.

What I have observed is that this double spacing is only between the first line of the `DESCRIPTION` and just after the first full stop of any paragraph.

Is there any reason for this? This is definitely not random (or a bug) as stated above there is a pattern. This has really irked my curiosity.

This what I see after I run `man more`. But I have observed this on almost every man page I have seen. I have tried this on my virtual machine also, so not a system bug (or glitch).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man page lines are full-justified, ie. they are both left- and right- aligned. Therefore some lines need larger spacing between words, and some smaller. The same occurs if you full-justify text in any word processor, eg. LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: Why isn't the double space observed uniformly throughout the document?

Comment: As I explained above: some lines need larger spacing (because they contain fewer characters), some need smaller (because they contain more characters). Sometimes you can see even triple spaces. Plus, not all man pages are formatted this way (full-justified), there are some that are left-justified only. Just the basics of typesetting :)